# How to add custom field to dhtmlxScheduler?

Tags: javascript, scheduler, dhtmlx

I want to add multiple custom fields to the lightbox in dhtmlScheduler. I realize that this is a dup of a [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613960/how-can-add-new-field-to-an-event-with-dhtmlx-scheduler) but that answer is incomplete/incorrect.

My application correctly stores and recalls data from a MySQL database using [dhtmlxDataProcessor](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxdataprocessor:toc) on the client and [dhtmlxConnector via PHP](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxconnector:start) on the server side. I have carefully read, re-read, and parsed documentation on [Custom "details" form](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxscheduler:custom_details_form#types_of_editors). I've worked with the code in the 05_custom_editor.html sample.

The problem is that those examples do not work - they silently fail to store the second field, "Details", in the Description section. This is not surprising since nowhere is the field mapped to a database column.

1. What changes are needed so the "Details" field of the example form stored in the database and recalled with the event?
2. What changes are needed to support read-only data in the Details field that is populate based on the "Text" field? What I'm thinking of is a name that has an address associated with it.
3. How to invoke a custom windows with a form from the lightbox to populate the address?

I would prefer to be able to do this by extending the default lightbox, but that is not a requirement.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I had to deliver this project in September so I switched away from DHTML due to lack of support and used jQuery-UI, CRUD, Twitter Bootstrap and custom JavaScript. I left the question open to perhaps help someone else. I no longer even have DHTMLX installed to test @David Newcomb's solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 required fields when using dhtmlScheduler. They are the first 3 in your PHP connector:

```
$scheduler->render_table("my_table","id","start_date,end_date,name,details,....
```

Your connector may use any column names as long as the order is preserved. But because it's required and used all over the place the dhtmlScheduler must refer to the name of the event. It is called "text".

The lightbox section maps description on to "text". I think that there is no

```
scheduler.locale.labels.section_description
```

for the same reason.

1) Update the PHP connector to pull in the required fields.
2) You can use sched.formSection('myfield') to get components from inside the lightbox, then you can add javascript to blur on focus.
3) Normal javascript

You can use one of the custom events alter any form items before you display the lightbox.

My dhtmlScheduler seems very vocal when it fails! What does the console say? Have you stepped through to see where it's failing?